# Can I apply tf.math.bincount on a rank 3 tensor without for loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, counting, rank, find-occurrences

I would like to get the occurrences of numbers of a 3 dimension tensor (displayed in a tensor at the corresponding indexes, like `tf.math.bincount` does).

For a 2d tensor, you can simply do this:

```
T = tf.round(25*tf.random.uniform((5,8)))
bincounts = tf.cast(tf.math.bincount(T, axis=-1),tf.float32)
```

But on a 3d tensor, the only way I found is looping over the third dimension, like this:

```
third_dim  = 10
T = tf.round(25*tf.random.uniform((5,8,third_dim)))
bincounts = []
for i in range(third_dim):
    bincounts.append(tf.math.bincount(T[:,:,i], axis=-1))
bincounts = tf.stack(bincounts,-1)
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to apply such a function directly on all the dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

Apply bincounts on the reshaped tensor, and then reshape back to the shape you want:

```
third_dim  = 10
T = tf.round(25*tf.random.uniform((5,8,third_dim)))
T2 = tf.reshape(T,(5*8,third_dim))
bincounts2 = tf.math.bincount(T2, axis=-1)
bincounts = tf.reshape(bincounts2, [5,8,bincounts2.shape[-1]])
```